# In javascript, is it possible to shorthand put all imports in an array for export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The current situation is like follows:

```js
// ./img/index.js:

import some-image from "./some-image.png";
import some-other-image from "./some-other-image.png";
// About 50 of these imports

export const imageArray = [some-image, some-other-image] //...and the other 48 imported images go in this array
```

This turn out, when typed in full, to be quite the lengthy export statement. What I want to achieve is fill the export imageArray with all the imported image in a more automated way without having to copy paste the var names from import.

Something like:

```
export const imageArray = [this.Imports];
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export, second-to-last of the "Aggregating modules" examples.

Comment: Are you using a module bundler? I assume so since you are importing images. That bundler probably has a way to import all files matching a pattern. Or you could write a simple script that generates the JavaScript file for you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That might be perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [babel-plugin-wildcard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-wildcard).

```
import * as images from "./images/*.png"

export default images
// or
export const imageArray = images
```

Comment: Thanks  for this awesome question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without any third module:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// In this example i supose you have only images at the folder!
async function getImages(folder) {
  const images = [];

  const files = await fs.promises.readdir(folder, { withFileTypes: true });
  for (let file of files) {
    images.push(path.join(__dirname, folder, file));
  }

  return images;
}

const imageArray = [];

// The '.' should be the path where are your images at.
const array = getImages('.'); 

// It could be like this or doing the reverse call when importing this imageArray...
array.forEach(el => {
  import image from el;
  imageArray.push(image)
});

export imageArray;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is going to work like you might expect. This is going to return the paths to all of the images, but it won't run them through a webpack loader or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the example! This did indeed return image paths rather than images for the browser to load, but as I did not specify that this is going to be very useful for people looking for the rel path approach!